# How to replace specific data of df based on an array having info about row to be changed

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

suppose I have a df

```
df1
   A       B       C
0  1   Apple     ABS
1  2  Banana     JYT
2  3    Cake     SDF
3  4   Apple     ABS
4  5    Cake     JYT
5  6    Cake     SDF
```

I want to copy value of column `B` in Column `C`  based on an array having values of `column A`.
`array1 = [2,4,5]`

changed `df1` will be

```
df1
   A       B       C
0  1   Apple     ABS
1  2  Banana     Banana     
2  3    Cake     SDF
3  4   Apple     Apple     
4  5    Cake     Cake     
5  6    Cake     SDF
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use boolean masking and `loc`:

```
df.loc[df['A'].isin(array1),'C']=df.loc[df['A'].isin(array1),'B']
```

OR

using `np.where()`

```
#import numpy as np
df['C']=np.where(df['A'].isin(array1),df['B'],df['C'])
```

output of `df`:

```
   A       B       C
0  1   Apple     ABS
1  2  Banana  Banana
2  3    Cake     SDF
3  4   Apple   Apple
4  5    Cake    Cake
5  6    Cake     SDF
```

Answer (score -1):

Find rows to update using `isin`, and then update column C from column B:

```
# find rows to update
rows_to_update = df.A.isin(array1)

# update rows in column C
df.C[rows_to_update] = df.B[rows_to_update]

df
   A       B       C
0  1   Apple     ABS
1  2  Banana  Banana
2  3    Cake     SDF
3  4   Apple   Apple
4  5    Cake    Cake
5  6    Cake     SDF
```

Comment: I tried this on columns having numeric data types. Rows that i want to update is correct but for others rows column c values become NaN

Comment: @Rrptm Not really sure. Just tried this on numeric data types, it works for me.